# Restrict Access for Function App with Azure API Manangement Service

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management

I have an API that uploads files to my Azure Storage account. This API consists of two Azure Functions: one is the API itself, while the second one is used as a file uploader. I want to restrict outside access to the file upload Azure Function, and only make it accessible through the API. Currently anyone can access the link to the file upload Azure Function, displaying the text "Your Functions 4.0 app is up and running". How would I go about restricting access?

I've tried IP address restriction, however when I do this it ends up blocking the API from accessing the file upload Azure Function. The file upload Azure Function's function.json folder also has "authLevel" set to "function".

Comment: if you use authorizationlevel.function, then only 'callers' with the proper key will be able to trigger the function execution.

Comment: That's what I've done, the authorization level is equal to function. Even in the networking options for the application, under "Access Restrictions" I've unchecked the box for "Allow public access", however this just prevents all traffic from using the function.

Comment: I think what you need is your APIM and function app integrated to the same VNET but different subnets and allow traffic from APIM subnet to the function subnet. This way your APIM can call your function API via the secure networking and your API can call the file upload function because it is within the same network. You can lock your function app so it cannot be called from any public IPs. Only calls within the private network will be allowed.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet?tabs=stv2

Comment: Enable VNet integration and configure access restrictions to allow traffic only from your API's IP address.

Comment: Right now I do not have a VNet, however if the solution purposed by @Jahnavi does not work then I will create one. If I create a VNet with all of my Azure services inside of it, will my API still be accessible to the public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To restrict Access for Function App with Azure API Management Service:

You can restrict access to the Azure functions with the `API` by generating function keys.

[image]

Goto `Azure function app -> functions`. Click on the specific function and go to `Function keys` under `Developer`.

Refer MSDoc for [Securing Azure functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/security-concepts?tabs=v4#function-access-keys).

You can restrict access via `authentication` under `app settings` in an app service. When accessing the function, users will be required to provide a valid function key in the request header.

In API code, make sure that you are including the generated function key in the request header according to the coding pattern you are using, when calling the file upload Azure function.

You can also restrict access via portal as shown in the below manner. Give access to the selected users or service principals with the help of identity providers as given.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I created the New Function key, however when I go to the Function App's settings and Authentication, the page that is presented to me is "Add an identity provider".

Comment: Add an identity provider then. @bowlingh23